# multiline random text using js

Tags: javascript, html, string, for-loop, random

I'm trying to make a **random text generator** that makes more than one line but it always goes on the same line on the HTML page (I have tried `\n` already and it doesn't work).

I tested it on chrome, but can I get some help please if its possible to even do.

Here the code I used: ([live demo](https://codepen.io/mcjoe21/pen/JjdOVYy))

```
function rtg(maxChar, maxLines) {
var ranChar = "";
var count;
var alphabet = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,56,7,8,9,0".split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
     var rand = null;
     for (var x = 0; x < maxChar; x++) {
         count++;
         rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
         ranChar += alphabet[rand];
         if (maxChar == count) {
          //this part i need help with
             ranChar += '\n'
             count = 0;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `<br/>`? As you display the data in a browser the html tag should work

Comment: `ranChar += '<br/>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some unnecessary variables here, so I've simplified your code a bit. `i` and `x` are your counts, so you don't really need a `count` variable. You should also use `<br/>` instead of `\n` if you're putting it in the HTML of the page.

```js
function rtg(maxChar, maxLines) {
  var lines = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
    if(i > 0) lines += "<br/>";
    for (var x = 0; x < maxChar; x++) lines += rando("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz1234567890");
  }
  return lines;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = rtg(12, 5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

This code uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify randomness, so if you want to use this code, just make sure you have this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

---

## In response to your comment:

if you want to link up your own external js file, you can make two files in the same directory: 1 html file, and 1 js file named "script.js". in the HTML file, use this as your HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the script.js file, use this:

```
function rtg(maxChar, maxLines) {
  var lines = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
    if(i > 0) lines += "<br/>";
    for (var x = 0; x < maxChar; x++) lines += rando("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz1234567890");
  }
  return lines;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = rtg(12, 5);
});
```

This has been tested and is working properly.

Comment: When I run js in a separate file and put the head to import the script it doesn't work (I put the randojs on top of my own js file)

Comment: Either there's an error in your js or you're not sourcing the script in properly. I've updated my answer to explain how to get it to work. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: the code i've given you works. what you're asking me now is a configuration issue on your end, and you should make another question post about it.

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is not recognised in HTML unless you use the css property `white-space: pre-line` (or put your text inside of a `<pre>Your Text Here</pre>` tag. Another way (probably preferable) would be to add `'<br/>'` instead of `'\n'` when you want to go to the next line

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` does both, though your not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new line in a string with "\n"